# How to solve bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have downloaded and installed RVM using [this guide](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-rvm-ruby-version-manager-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/). However when I run `/bin/bash --login` so as to switch to a different ruby version I get the following error `bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory`. How can I fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM have dedicated Ubuntu package, so please follow instructions posted here: https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm (taken from here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

Otherwise, you can skip that step and just use the next command in the tutorial, `rvm use 3.0.0` or whatever version you want.